# How to prove that a 2-place function is a ratio

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for all reals $x, y, z, f(x, y)f(y, z) = f(x, z)$.  Can we show that $f(x, y) = T(x)/T(y)$ for some function $T$?

This is used in a thermodynamics textbook to construct absolute temperature.

Comment: For all $z$, $f(x,y) = f(x,z)/f(y,z)$.  Let $T(x) = f(x,0)$.  This does gloss over what do do if $f(y,z) = 0$, but then again, the statement isn't even true in all such cases (for example, $f(x,y) = 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that either $f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $x,y$ or we have $f(x,y)$ identically zero (see below for the justification). I'll assume the former.

Now notice that $f(x,x)f(x,y) = f(x,y)$ so $f(x,x) = 1$.

Then notice that $f(x,y)f(y,x) = f(x,x)$ so $f(y,x) = f(x,y)^{-1}$.

Now fix any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $T(x) = f(x,c)$. Then $f(x,y) = f(x,c)f(c,y) = T(x) f(y,c)^{-1} = T(x) T(y)^{-1}$.

[A nice alternative approach, if we may assume $f(x,y) > 0$ for all $x,y$, is to take logs, which makes this a bit more intuitive with all the products turned into sums.]

---

What if we have $f(x,y) = 0$ for some $x$ and $y$? Then $f(x,z) = f(x,y)f(y,z) = 0$ for all $z$. Then $f(w,z) = f(w,x)f(x,z) = 0$ for all $w$, so the function is identically zero.